# 'printf' followed by 'scanf' requires pressing ENTER key twice to accept input

Tags: c

I'm a complete beginner in C programming and I have a question. I'll bring a simple code as an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int x;
    printf( "Please type the number 10." );
    scanf( "%i\n", &x );

    if ( x == 10 )
        printf( "Thank you!\n" );


    return 0;
}
```

As expected, when I compile and run this program, my terminal displays the message:

```
"Please type the number 10."
```

Then it waits for input, so I type the number it asks for (10), and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. The problem is that after I press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> once, it moves to a new line and waits for more input. Only after typing 10 and pressing ENTER again does it actually move on (... to display "Thank you!").

So it appears that I have to press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> twice for my input to be accepted. Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Are you sure it only happens after a `printf`?

Comment: Change it to `scanf( "%i", &x );` (no \n)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually `scanf` doesn't emit prompt and if you include any thing other than format specifier then you have to enter input inexactly that way that's why you are required to press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> again.

Change this :

```
scanf( "%i\n", &x );
        // ^
        // |  remove extra \n
```

to this:

```
scanf( "%i", &x );
```

Comment: Yep, I removed the '\n' and it solved the problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Since we're here to learn I guess I could return you a favor by correcting you slightly, too; it's wholeheartedly, not whole heartily :)

Comment: @user2577148 haha I know that but actually I was writing "whole" and "heartedly"  separately and that's why it was underlined red. Anyway thanks for that correction and yes, you are wholeheartedly welcome :) :)

Answer (score 8):

It's the "\n" in your call to `scanf`. Remove that and `scanf` will return after scanning the integer value you requested.

Note: This has nothing to do with the fact that the `scanf` call is preceded by a `printf`.